# How to convert DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>?

Tags: dbcontext

Im trying to convert code using entity framework but i dont know how to do it.
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHqG.png)

ill try to use this code, but the output is different in cout row in table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Zt1.png)